# Project Professional 2010 can't publish existing project file

Tags: microsoft-project, publishing

I have an existing project file (created in project 2007 professional), opened by me in project professional 2010, and saved.

I open this newly saved file, and connect to Project Server (2010) using my credentials (I'm admin), now when I try and publish this existing project, I can't because the button is grayed out.

If I start from a blank file, I can publish without any issues (so its not permissions).

I suspect something is wrong with the template for this project, but I have no idea what, any idea what to check for?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a matter of permissions.

Verify against this article : [Project 2010: Project Permissions](http://www.pmtoolbox.com/project-management-news/project-2010-project-permissions.html).

Comment: Permissions can be elimated, since I'm logged in as administrator and can create / public new projects - but only if the project file starts off blank and I create it from scratch. This existing project file I have has been around since before we installed project server.

Comment: @JL: I didn't mean Windows permissions. I was thinking along the lines that some meta-data inside the converted project, dating from Project 2007, is causing your problems.